# Error: AttributeError: file <maya console> line 65: 'OptionsWindow' object has no attribute 'int_offset' #

Tags: python, maya, attributeerror

I'm getting this error for line 65 of my Python code in Maya within the pasteTheseKeys method:

```
self.offsetVal = mc.intFieldGrp(self.int_offset, q=True, value1=True)
```

pasteTheseKeys is called when the "Paste Keys" button is pressed. That relationship is defined in the commonButtons method.

The complete code:

```
# Animation Copy Tool
# Bakari Holmes 5/2/2015
# This is designed to copy and existing animation
# from one rig to another and make the process easier
# with a simple UI
# !!!Make sure you select keyframes in the graph editor to have them displayed before pasting!!!

import maya.cmds as mc
import functools
import maya.mel as mm
import pprint

"""OptionsWindow is a class definition of the basic window class.
   The class is adding a set of controls to create a template
   that resembles Maya's built-in tool option windows."""

class OptionsWindow(object):
    #@classmethod
    def showUI(cls):
        win = cls()
        win.create()
        return win
    def __init__(self):
        self.window = "Animation Copy Tool"
        self.title = "Animation Copier"
        self.size = (546,350)
    def create(self):
        if mc.window(self.window,exists=True): 
            mc.deleteUI(self.window,window=True)

        self.window = mc.window(self.window, title=self.title,widthHeight=self.size,menuBar=True)
        self.mainForm = mc.formLayout(nd=100)
        self.commandMenu()
        self.commonButtons()
        self.optionsBorder = mc.tabLayout(scrollable=True,height=1)
        mc.formLayout(self.mainForm,e=True,attachForm=([self.optionsBorder,"top",0],[self.optionsBorder,"left",2],[self.optionsBorder,"right",2]),attachControl=([self.optionsBorder,"bottom",5,self.applyBtn]))
        self.optionsForm=mc.formLayout(nd=100)
        mc.tabLayout(self.optionsBorder,edit=True,tabLabel=(self.optionsForm,"Test"))
        self.displayOptions()
        self.tx_src = mc.textFieldGrp(label="Source Object", editable=False, text=sel[0])
        self.int_offset = mc.intFieldGrp(label="Frame Offset Amount", value1=0)
        mc.showWindow()

    def commandMenu(self):
        self.editMenu = mc.menu(label="Edit")
        self.editMenuSave = mc.menuItem(label="Save Settings",command=self.editMenuSaveCmd)
        self.editMenuReset = mc.menuItem(label="Reset Settings",command=self.editMenuResetCmd)
        self.helpMenu = mc.menu(label="Help")
        self.helpMenuItem = mc.menuItem(label="Help on %s"%(self.title),command=self.helpMenuCmd)
    def helpMenuCmd(self,*args):
        mc.launch(web="http://maya-python.com")
    def editMenuSaveCmd(self,*args):pass
    def editMenuResetCmd(self,*args):pass

    def applyBtnCmd(self,*args):pass
    def closeBtnCmd(self,*args):
        mc.deleteUI(self.window,window=True)

    #paste operation
    def pasteTheseKeys(self):
        self.offsetVal = mc.intFieldGrp(self.int_offset, q=True, value1=True)
        self.selObj_pasteKeys = mc.ls(sl=True)

        for objectQuant in selObj_pasteKeys:
            print objectQuant
            self.ct = mc.currentTime(query = True)
            self.t = self.ct + self.offsetVal
            mc.currentTime(self.t)
            # mc.selectKey(selObj_pasteKeys[objectQuant])
            mc.pasteKey(time=(self.t, self.t), f=(1.0,1.0), option="merge", copies=1, to=0, fo=0, vo=0)

    def commonButtons(self):
        self.commonBtnSize=(self.size[0]-18/3,26)
        self.acctionBtn=mc.button(label="Paste Keys", command = self.pasteTheseKeys(), height=self.commonBtnSize[1])

        self.closeBtn = mc.button(label="Close",height=self.commonBtnSize[1],command=self.closeBtnCmd)


        mc.formLayout(self.mainForm, e=True, attachForm=([self.acctionBtn,"left",5],
                                                     [self.acctionBtn,"bottom",5],
                                                     [self.closeBtn,"bottom",5],
                                                     [self.closeBtn,"right",5]),
                                         attachPosition=([self.acctionBtn,"right",1,33],
                                                         [self.closeBtn,"left",0,67]),
                                         #attachControl=([self.applyBtn,"left",4,self.acctionBtn],
                                                      #  [self.applyBtn,"right",4,self.closeBtn]),
                                         attachNone=([self.acctionBtn,"top"],
                                                     [self.closeBtn,"top"]))
    def displayOptions(self):pass

#########################    
# end of class definition
#########################

def keys_as_dictionary(channel):
    """return a dictionay of times:values for <channel>"""
    keys = mc.keyframe(channel, q=True, tc=True) or []
    values = mc.keyframe(channel, q=True, vc=True) or []
    return dict(zip(keys, values))

def channels(object):
    """return a dictionary of <plug>:<channel_dict> for each animated plug selected"""
    keys = mc.keyframe(object, sl=True, n=True, q=True)
    result = {}

    for k in keys:
        plugs = mc.listConnections(k, p=True)[0]
        result[plugs]= keys_as_dictionary(k)
    return result



copyAnim="copyAnim"

#store selected object info
sel = mc.ls(selection=True)
print sel

if (len(sel) != 1):
    mm.eval("warning Must select one animated object;")

else:
    mc.copyKey()
    win = OptionsWindow()
    win.create()

    pprint.pprint(channels(sel))
```

I've been combing through the other entries here on Attribute errors and instance attributes vs. class attributes but am still quite confused as to why I'm getting this error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, an attribute may be accessed only after its value was set for the first time. This is true regardless of whether the attribute is a class attribute or an instance attribute.

In this particular case, it seems like you are trying to access the attribute `int_offset` before it's set for the first time.

Analyzing your code reveals that the attribute `int_offset` is first set towards the end of the method `create()` while it is referenced before that line of code is reached. In fact, a bit earlier in the method `create()`, the method `commonButtons()` is invoked which in turn invokes the method `pasteTheseKeys()` which references the attribute `int_offset`, that has not yet had the chance to get defined.

Comment: Thank you so much!  Always the simple things that can easily escape notice.  Now to fix the layout of my GUI...